# determining when users uninstall my app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, uninstallation

I have a 50% uninstall rate on my mobile app. I'm looking for some insights. I'd like to know more details on how quickly users uninstall, how deep users explored my app before they uninstalled and the path they navigated through my app. Through these metrics, I may be able to determine some patterns that could help me improve my app. Is there a way through Google Analytics or the Development Console to determine these metrics?